# glassfish 3.1.1 jar files for eclipse indigo in maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, glassfish, glassfish-3, eclipse-indigo

i am glassfish newbie

in eclipse indigo, if you create a dynamic web project (with glassfish 3.1.1 as the target runtime, assuming you have installed the relevant server adaptor), there will be a lot of jar files included in your classpath.

what are the equivalent maven' dependencies to load those jars at the classpath?

i have embedded glassfish (a maven dependency) for testing. however, the maven dependencies for testing apparently collide with the eclipse included glassfish jars when i do testing (no problem otherwise when i am not doing testing).

thus, i want to move those eclipse included glassfish jars to maven dependencies. however, there are so many jar files i don't know how to begin.

any assistance is appreciated. thank you :D